# Converter not entered for Image in ToolTip

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, tooltip, dimensions

I've got a `DataTemplate` which I use for items in a `ListBox` (a grid with the first column showing an icon depending on the file extension, the second column containing the file name):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="16"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="16" Height="16">
        <Image.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ToolTipImage, Converter={StaticResource toolTipImageConverter}}" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=ToolTipImage, Converter={StaticResource toolTipImageConverter}}">
                <Image Source="{Binding FileNameForThumbnailDisplay}" Name="ToolTipImage">
                    <Image.RenderTransform >
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"></ScaleTransform>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
            </ToolTip>
        </Image.ToolTip>
    </Image>
    <Label Content="{Binding FileNameWithExtension, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Height="Auto"></Label>
</Grid>
```

I'd like to show a `ToolTip` containing a scaled down `Image` when hovering over an icon in the first column. This is what works, but what I'd like to achieve is to also reduce the `ToolTip` displaying the image according to the dimensions of the scaled down image, e.g. something like this:

Image abc in listbox:

```
+--ToolTip-------+
|+-Scaled-Image-+|
||              ||
||              ||
|+--------------+|
+----------------+
```

Image xyz in listbox:

```
+--ToolTip-----------------+
|+-Scaled-Image-----------+|
||                        ||
||                        ||
|+------------------------+|
+--------------------------+
```

I  wrote a `Converter` to return the `ActualWidth` (of the rendered `Image` element) to set the dimensions, but the converter is never entered.

I needed I could supply the code used for the `Converter`, however, I don't think it's relevant as it isn't entered (break point while debugging is never hit).

How can I achieve that the `ToolTip` control's dimensions dynamically adjust to the image within? Is this possible?

Comment: Are there any binding exceptions in output window?

Comment: No, checked for them as well, but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `RenderTranform` to `LayoutTransform` and don't bind `Width` or `Height`. The ToolTip window will fit to size automatically.

```
<Image.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip>  
        <Image Source="{Binding FileNameForThumbnailDisplay}" Margin="4">
            <Image.LayoutTransform> 
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/> 
            </Image.LayoutTransform> 
        </Image>
    </ToolTip>
</Image.ToolTip>
```